# How to set the on-click image for a button in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to set the on-click image for a button in Windows Phone 7?

Here is my code:

```
 <Button Name="refresh" Margin="320,-630,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="75" Width="75" BorderThickness="0" Click="refresh_Click">
                        <Button.Foreground>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/DataCollector.Tone;component/Resources/refresh-pressed.png" />
                        </Button.Foreground>
                        <Button.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/DataCollector.Tone;component/Resources/refresh.png" />
                        </Button.Background>
                    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Template>
         <ControlTemplate>
              <Image .... />
         </ControlTemplate>
     </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `VisualStateManager`. You can click `Template - Edit a Copy` in Expression Blend and get a standard template for a `Button` with all states. Then you can make `Normal` and `Pressed` states as you would like